# Microsoft Power BI: RANKX AND AGGREGATION OF RESULT

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am having an issues ranking a set of rows then getting the total to use as input to another calculation. I have attempted nested CALCULATE statements and intermediate table using CALCULATETABLE unsuccessfully.
Scenario is as follows:

Original table

```
Item Sales
A     3
B     4
C     2
D     7
E     5
```

Ranking top N (3)

```
Item Sales
D     7
E     5
B     4
TOTAL 16
```

In this example, I am interested in the value 16 for onward processing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a CALCULATED COLUMN to rank the sales.

```
Sale Rank = RANK.EQ(SalesData[Sales], SalesData[Sales])
```

Create a MEASURE to get the top 3 sales.

```
Top 3 Sales = CALCULATE(SUM(SalesData[Sales]), SalesData[Sale Rank] <= 3)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Murray, thanks for you quick response. Your answer is correct however, I missed out an important detail.  The actual issue is that I am unable to do this when I have to first aggregate a category of data. If you modify the sample data as follows: Item Sales
A 3
B 1
B 4
C 2
D 7
E 5
E 1  aggregate the data to end up with the table below with a total of 18 Item Sales
D 7
E 6
B 5
TOTAL 18
In my case, when I follow any logic include yours, I get the error message "A function calculate has been used in a true/false expression that is used as a table filter expression"

Comment: Original table 
Item Sales
A 3
B 1
B 4
C 2
D 7
E 5
E 1

Comment: Ranking top 3 
Item Sales
D 7
E 6
B 5
TOTAL 18

Comment: Item E & B have 2 rows each which need to be aggregated first

Comment: Based on the original question, I will mark this is a correct then raise a different question